# How do I spare Undyne?

Tags: undertale

She keeps attacking me, and no matter how many times I either try to use any <kbd>ACT</kbd> option, she doesn't permit me to <kbd>SPARE</kbd> her. Is there any peaceful way out of this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To spare Undyne, you need to survive her waves of attacks until she changes your heart back to red and throw a spear at you.

Run during this turn.

When you get on the overworld map, Undyne will be stunned for a moment. Use this to run upwards. She will catch up with you and will attack you again. Keep running when your heart is turned to red again. You need to do this three times in total.

After three waves, Undyne will no longer turn your heart green. At this moment on just run all the way to Hotland. Around halfway on the screen that displays "Welcome to Hotland", Papyrus will call you (if you spared him), giving you a moment to relax. Undyne will not move during the phone call.

On the first screen of Hotland, you have a few additional seconds because she 
will stop for a moment and get angry at Sans.

She will collapse on the next screen, because her armor overheats. If you want to befriend her later on you need to give her water from the nearby water cooler.

Comment: Fight, then run, then keep running, accept the phone call, find safety in the lava stage, use water cooler. <- Stuff like this is why I love Undertale

Comment: Note: Once Undyne collapses in Hotland, she's spared no matter what you do. If you don't give her the water, it won't kill her, you just won't be able to befriend her. She'll be grumbling at home and won't answer the door.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Excellent. BTW - if you weren't aware - to get my attention with a comment, just include an @ followed by my name and it'll notify me. I just happened to wander back in here this time. =P

Comment: anything interesting out of being mean to her? does it close the friendship end? I guess but must be sure :P

Comment: @gia it won't matter at all. The date will always succeed if the conditions have been met.

Comment: She gets angry at Sans for sleeping on the job.